Show that from a system of closed intervals covering an open interval it is not always possible to choose a finite subsystem covering the interval

Show that


a) from a system of closed intervals covering a closed interval it is not always possible to choose a ﬁnite subsystem covering the interval;


b) from a system of open intervals covering an open interval it is not always possible to choose a ﬁnite subsystem covering the interval;


c) from a system of closed intervals covering an open interval it is not always possible to choose a ﬁnite subsystem covering the interval.

---- Zorich Mathematical Analysis I 2.3 Exercise 2
My attempt for all of the questions is the following:
Proof for a)
Let$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}{[0,1-\frac 1 n]}=[0,1]$
For any $x\in(0,1]\subset\mathbb R,\:\exists n\in\mathbb N\:$such that$\: nx>1$
But$\:0\:\notin (0,1],$And that  $\:0\cdot n=0<1\:\forall n\in N$
It is shown that there isn't a finite subsystem covering the interval.
Therefore from a system of closed intervals covering a closed interval it is not always possible to choose a finite subsystem covering the interval.
Proof for b)
Let $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n=(\frac 1 2,1)\cup\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 2}}(0,\frac 1 2-\frac 1 {n+1})=(0,1)$
For any $$x\in (0,1)\implies x\in(\frac 1 2,1)\vee x\in(0,\frac 1 2-\frac 1 3)\vee x\in(0,\frac 1 2-\frac 1 4)\vee\cdots$$
$x=\frac{1} {2}\in (0,1)\quad$But $x$ cannot be covered by finite subsystem
Therefore a system of open intervals covering an open interval doesn't always have a finite subsystem covering the interval.
Proof of c)
Let$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{[a+\frac{1} {n},b-\frac{1} {n}]}$
Because $a,b\notin (a,b)$, there aren't a finite subsystem covering the open interval.
I think my proof and construction is unrigorous, and especially for c).
The reason why is for I think that my proof for c) is that how can we prove that there aren't finite subcoverings covering the range $(a,b)$ when as $I_n$'s n progresses, it is covering more and more of $(a,b)$. Can't I just choose the greatest n and call that a finite covering and call it a day?
So may someone help me to give a more rigorous proof and also I noticed that these concepts are from topology, so maybe can you tell me what concepts are these corresponding to, and in order to give a formal proof. Thank you.
Edit:

It seems that the proof of a) is wrong, since that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}{[0,1-\frac 1 n]}=[0,1).$
It seems also that the proof of b) is wrong,
since that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 2}}(0,\frac 1 2-\frac 1 {n+1})\ne (0,\frac 1 2]$

Edit 2:
Seems like for b) We can let $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n=(0,a_1]\cup (a_1,a_2]\cup\cdots$for all $a_i<a_{i+1},a_i<1$
And for a) we can use $\bigcup_{x\in(0,1)}[x,x]$

Hi! I think this is a fine question. However, over time, there's been more emphasis on asking people who post proof-verification questions to narrow their focus on exactly which part of their proof(s) their doubts are about. To avoid down-votes and close-votes, can you be more specific about which proof? Maybe focus on what your doubts about part (c) are, particularly?

$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[ 0, 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right] = \left[0, 1 \right) \neq \left[ 0, 1\right]$

I do not follow your proof for $(a)$; what is the closed interval that cannot be covered?
An alternative proof is to consider $\bigcup_{x \in [0, 1]} [x, x]$. This is a system of closed intervals that cover $[0, 1]$ but clearly any finite subset cannot cover $[0, 1]$.
I also spot a problem with $(b)$. I do not agree that
$$\left( \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right) \cup \bigcup_{n=2}^\infty \left( 0, \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n + 1} \right) = \left( 0, 1 \right)$$
because
$$\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty \left( 0, \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n + 1} \right) = \left( 0, \frac{1}{2} \right)$$
Instead consider $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left( 0, 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right) = \left( 0, 1 \right)$. No finite subsystem can cover $(0, 1)$.
Your solution for $(c)$ is correct. To make it more rigorous, consider any finite subsystem $I_{n_i} = \left[ a + \frac{1}{n_i}, b - \frac{1}{n_i} \right]$ for $i \in \{1, 2, \dots, N \}$ and note
$$\bigcup_{i = 1}^N I_{n_i} = \left[ a + \min \left\lbrace \frac{1}{n_i} \right\rbrace, b - \min \left\lbrace \frac{1}{n_i} \right\rbrace \right] \overset{\text{strict}}{\subset} \left( a, b \right)$$

it is $[a+\frac 1 n, b-\frac 1 n]$ for $n\in\mathbb N$

Ah, yes. You are right, I will update my answer.

I think you made a mistake by typing $[a,b]$ as $(a,b)$, if it is $(a,b)$, there wouldn't exists finite subsystem covering $(a,b)$ since you marked that the inclusion is strict.

Right, there doesn't exist a finite subsystem covering $(a, b)$. That is what we are trying to prove.

Ah yes. I just noticed.

Can you please make a proof of a) and b)?

Ok, I filled out my answer for $(b)$. If should be straightforward to make it more rigorous, but I encourage you to try it yourself. Follow what I did for part $(c)$, ie. "consider any finite subcover..."

Thank you, I accepted it.
